# What is the numerical stability of std::pow() compared to iterated multiplication?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, numerical-methods

What sort of stability issues arise or are resolved by using `std::pow()`?

- Will it be more stable (or faster, or at all different) in general to implement a simple function to perform `log(n)` iterated multiplies if the exponent is known to be an integer?
- How does `std::sqrt(x)` compare, stability-wise, to something of the form `std::pow(x, k/2)`? Would it make sense to choose the method preferred for the above to raise to an integer power, then multiply in a square root, or should I assume that `std::pow()` is fast and accurate to machine precision for this? If `k = 1`, is there a difference from `std::sqrt()`?
- How would `std::pow(x, k/2)` or the method above compare, stability-wise, to an integer exponentiation of `std::sqrt(x)`?

And as a bonus, what are the speed differences likely to be?

Comment: You're asking a question of which parts are amenable to experimentation and analysis. What are the results of your experiments and analysis ?

Comment: Pascal Cuoq's answer is excellent, but I would add that lots of traditional and popular implementations of `pow` are outrageously crappy.

Comment: @tmyklebu, which ones?

Comment: @trbabb I almost mentioned this but it just complicated the message. There are a number of confused questions on this site caused by `pow(10.0, 2.0)` evaluating to a double other than `100.0` on Windows (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851636/is-this-a-g-bug ). Since the mathematical result is exactly representable as the double `100.0`, it means that that `pow` function commits an error of more than 1ULP. But even if you use a botched `pow` function that is sometimes wrong by, say, 1.5 ULP, it remains more accurate than four multiplications.

Comment: @trbabb: I haven't catalogued them, but I've seen a fairly recent Linux machine's `pow` be garbage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Will it be more stable (or faster, or at all different) in general to implement a simple function to perform log(n) iterated multiplies if the exponent is known to be an integer?

The result of [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) for integer exponents is in general less accurate than `pow`, but both are stable in the sense that close inputs produce close results. You can expect exponentiation by squaring to introduce 0.5 ULP of relative error by multiplication (for instance, 1 ULP of error for computing x<sup>3</sup> as `x * x * x`).

When the second argument n is statically known to be 2, then by all means implement x<sup>n</sup> as `x * x`. In that case it is faster and more accurate than any possible alternative.

> How does std::sqrt(x) compare, stability-wise, to something of the form std::pow(x, k/2)

First, the accuracy of `sqrt` cannot be beat for an IEEE 754 implementation, because `sqrt` is one of the basic operations that this standard mandates to be as accurate as possible.

But you are not asking about `sqrt`, you are asking (I think) about <computation of x<sup>n</sup>> * sqrt(x) as opposed to `pow(x, n + 0.5)`. Again, in general, for a quality implementation of `pow`, you can expect `pow(x, n + 0.5)` to be more accurate than the alternatives. Although `sqrt(x)` would be computed to 0.5 ULP, the multiplication introduces its own approximation of up to 0.5 ULP, and all in all, it is better to obtain the result you are interested in in a single call to a well-implemented function. A quality implementation of `pow` will give you 1 ULP of accuracy for its result, and the best implementations will “guarantee” 0.5 ULP.

> And as a bonus, what are the speed differences likely to be?

If you know in advance that the exponent is going to be a small integer or multiple of 0.5, then you have information that the implementer of `pow` did not have, so you can beat them by at least the cost of the test to determine that the second argument is a small integer. Plus, the implementer of a quality implementation is aiming for a more accurate result than simple exponentiation by squaring provides. On the other hand, the implementer of `pow` can use extremely sophisticated techniques to minimize the average execution time despite the better accuracy: see for instance [CRlibm's implementation](https://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/cgi-bin/fplibrary/cvsweb.cgi/crlibm/pow.c?rev=1.17;content-type=text%2Fplain;cvsroot=crlibm;logsort=cvs;f=H). I put the verb “guarantee” above inside quotes when talking about the best implementations of `pow` because `pow` is one function for which CRlibm's 0.5 ULP accuracy guarantee is [only “with astronomical probability”](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/frs/download.php/153/crlibm-1.0beta3.pdf).

Comment: link to CRlibm seems broken or site down?