# Why does floor(pow(64,1.0/3)) return 3 but print 4 when the floor() is removed in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, math

I need to find the floor nth root of a given number(x). `x` can be as large as `1e12` and `n` can be as large as 50. `floor(pow(64,1.0/3))` returns `3`, please help me with this problem, if not can you please suggest an alternative taking the keeping in mind?
**Edit:** I know its about floating point precision, I am asking what the alternative should be in such situations.
Even the following code returns `True`

`double x = pow(64,1.0/3);
return x==(int)x;`

Comment: Because the floor of 3.999999999 is 3 and not 4.  Look at the result as a decimal not an integer.

Comment: And `1.0/3` is not exactly one third. Floating point is just an approximation of the real numbers.

Comment: And thats why I asked for an alternative :/

Comment: The "alternative" is to realize what floating point values are (binary representation of decimal real numbers), thus they are approximations, as already stated.  It's up to you to recognize this and rearrange your calculations accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is the underlying resp. surrounding problem? Why do you exclude to use `round(pow(64,1.0/3))` to get the closest integer to the result?

Comment: I need the floor specifically. Its actually a problem in competitive programming.

Comment: Then use `floor(pow(64,1.0/3)+1e-15)` to skip over the noise in the last bits of the mantissa.

Comment: @IstasisMishra If it is a competitive programming is every other competitor using C++, or some other language that uses fixed floating point or arbitrary precision types?  If so, then you're at a disadvantage using C++, as those types do not natively exist.  You would either have to write your own library, or use the available ones such as [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with good old floating-point imprecision.  See [What is the numerical stability of std::pow() compared to iterated multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636392), and especially [Pascal Cuoq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636644/3233921), for an in-depth explanation why the result of `std::pow` in particular will be imprecise.  Because of rounding errors, you will occasionally get a result that is *ever so slightly* less than 4, and so `std::floor` will round down to 3.

The answer I linked above says:

> A quality implementation of `pow` will give you 1 ULP of accuracy for its result, and the best implementations will “guarantee” 0.5 ULP.

ULP here refers to the [Unit of Least Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) or Unit in the Last Place.  Knowing about this error, you can increase the `std::pow()` result before calling `std::floor`.  A good way to do this is using [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter), which gives you the next-larger representable floating-point value (i.e., 1 ULP up).  I think that if Pascal's statement on the precision of `std::pow()` holds, calling `nextafter` once should put you back above 4, in your particular example.  Here's the code I recommend:

```
template <typename T>
T floorroot2(T x, T e)
{
  const auto r = std::pow(x, T(1.0)/e);
  return std::floor(std::nextafter(r, r+1));
}
```

That works for me ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acdea2f24b615781)), but if you want to be extra sure if you don't trust your library's `pow` implementation, you may want to add 2 ULPs, i.e. call `nextafter(nextafter(r, r+1), r+1)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
Type compute(Type v1, Type v2, Type v3)
{
    return std::floor(std::pow(v1, v2 / v3));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << compute<float>(64, 1, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << compute<double>(64, 1, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << compute<long double>(64, 1, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
4
3
4
```