# Unexpected result with pow() function in C++

Tags: c++

I've written this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,n,result;

    cout<<"enter the value"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    cout<<"enter the power"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    result=pow(x,n);
    cout<<"the result of power\t"<<x<<"to\t"<<n<<"=\t"<<result;
}
```

When I assign `x=10 n=2` the result is 99 not 100.
When i change  x,n,result to float type, the output is x=10 n=2 result=100.

Can someone explain me why this difference?

Comment: First learn that [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is a *floating point* function, then see that [floating point math is *not* broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/440558).

Comment: You're (unknowingly) using floating point calculations. Converting floating point numbers to integers is a source of errors. If you instead printed `pow(x,n)` directly you would get a more reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about reading C++ reference? Here is [what you can find about `pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/):

> double pow (double base, double exponent);
>   float pow (float base, float exponent);
>   long double pow (long double base, long double exponent);
>   double pow (Type1 base, Type2 exponent);        // additional overload

As you can see, there is no `pow()` for integer arguments, but you may use casting, like:

```
int x, n;  
{...}  
double result=pow(double(x),double(n));
```

More informations were written here: [Why is my integer math with std::pow giving the wrong answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851636/why-is-my-integer-math-with-stdpow-giving-the-wrong-answer)