# My code for creating new numbers with different digits from an 2D array sometimes doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, arrays, pow

I am beginner in C++ and I am creating a cows and bulls(player) program.
The program works by making a 2D boolean array(p) for the numbers and their position.When i try to create a new possible number sometimes it seems that when it adds the next digit by multiplying it by the proper power of 10 it adds one less(399 instead of 400).I have no idea why this is happening.Here is the code:

```
      #include <iostream>
      #include <cmath>
      #include <math.h>
      #include <algorithm>
      #include <random>
      ....
      random_device rd;
      mt19937 gen(rd());
      uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1,9);
      for (int s7=0;s7<=3;s7++)
      {
         for (bool s1=0;s1!=1;)
         {
             int k=0;
             bool z=0;
             k=dis(gen);
             for (int s8=0;s8<=3;s8++)
             {
                 if (k==nm[s8]) z=1;
             }
             if (p[k][s7]==0 && z==0 && k!=0)
             {

                 s1=1;
                 b=b+k*pow(10.0,s7);
                 cout <<k*pow(10.0,s7)<<"  "<<b<<endl;
                 nm[s7]=k;
             }
         }
      }
```

(The first few lines i got from internet)
and here is the output:
1  1
50  51
900  950
2000  2950
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `std::pow` is not precise since it works with floating point numbers. You need to define a function that does the same thing with integral numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851636/why-is-my-integer-math-with-stdpow-giving-the-wrong-answer

Comment: Thank you,
I will try it out