# Every possible combination of string

Tags: c++, string, permutation

**I have to get every possible combination of given string**.
The string I get can be of various sizes but always **contains only 1 and 0**.

For example, **Combinations I want to get** with "101" as the input :

"000" "001" "010" "100" "110" "101" "011" "111".

I tried using std::next_permutation (c++20), I'm getting close but this not exactly not what I want.

The final goal is to store every combination inside a string vector.

Below is what I tried with next_permutation

```
// I'm not using *using namespace std* no need to mention it
std::vector<std::string>    generate_all_combinations(std::string base)
{
   std::vector<std::string> combinations;
   do {
       combinations.push_back(base);
   } while (std::next_permutation(base.begin(), base.end()));
   return combinations;
}
```

When I print the vector's content I have :
"011" "101" "110".

The base strings "000" and "111" are not a problem I can generate those pretty easily. But I'm still lacking other combinations like "001" "010" "100".

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in function, or no? Also, why would you need an input if it always returns that same thing? Might just be me.

Comment: start with an all zero string, `"0000"`, then replace one of the `0`'s with a `1`, call `next_permutation` until you've cycled through all permutations, repeate.

Comment: Not particularly no, just seeking help that's all. That was just an example. The string always contains zeros and ones but can be of various sizes. I need to be able to generate every possible one and zero combinations for every given string length.

Comment: Is there a maximum size for the input string?

Comment: Do you know how to add 1 to a binary number with pen and paper?

Comment: I'll actually go ahead and mention the fact that you aren't `using namespace std`. It's better not to use it, so well done, keep on doing so.

Comment: @user253751 yes I do

Comment: @paolo not really, I don't have any time or memory usage constraints either

Comment: @NathanOliver your solution seems to be working ! I'm trying things out to make just to make sure but it seems good !

Comment: If you start with 00000000 and keep adding 1 until you get to 11111111, that's all 8-character combinations of 0 and 1.

Comment: To paraphrase a bit: *"When I [start with `"011"`and] print the vector's content I have [all permutations involving two `1`s and one `0`]. The strings [with all `0`s and all `1`s] are not a problem I can generate those pretty easily. But I'm still lacking [all permutations of one `1` and two `0`s]."*-- which is how permutations work.

Comment: @ArminMontigny It's exactly what the OP is looking for. ("Combinations", "Permutations", and "the input" confuse the situation, but look at their exact request.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer you expect, but if you want every binary combination for a specified count of bits, this is one possible solution:

```
  void getCombinations(std::vector<std::string>& str_list, int len)
  {
    uint64_t comb_count = 1ull << len;

    std::string str;

    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < comb_count; ++i) {

      str.clear();

      for(int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        str += ((i >> j) & 0x1) ? "1" : "0";

      str_list.push_back(str);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should not use `pow` to calculate the integer power of 2. `1ull << len` is better.

Answer (score 0):

`std::next_permutation` won't work here, you will have to craft your own function here.

For example, for a symbol list "ab" where the permutations have a length of 3, you can get the 4th permutation by converting the number 4 to base 2 (length of symbol list) and use that as an index table for your permutation.

so 4 becomes `100` in base 2, so the indices are `{1, 0, 0}` and for the symbol list that is `'b', 'a', 'a'` therefore the string `"baa"`.

---

Here is a possible implementation of this, and it takes a symbol list, permutation length and current number of permutation. You can manually convert to any base by diving by base^position and taking modulus of base. The base is simply the length of the symbol list:

```
template<std::integral T>
constexpr T int_pow(T b, T e) {
    return (e == 0) ? T{ 1 } : b * int_pow(b, e - 1);
}

std::string get_permutation(const std::string& symbols, std::size_t permutation_size, std::size_t position) {
    std::string permutation;
    permutation.resize(permutation_size);

    auto base = symbols.length();

    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < permutation_size; ++i) {

        auto index = (position / int_pow(base, i)) % base;
        permutation[permutation_size - i - 1] = symbols[index];
    }
    return permutation;
}
```

so calling this:

```
std::cout << get_permutation("ab", 3u, 4u) << '\n';
```

prints out

```
baa
```

---

with this function you can make a `list_permutations` function, that adds all permutations to a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> list_permutations(const std::string& symbols, std::size_t permutation_size) {

    auto result_size = std::size_t(std::pow(symbols.length(), permutation_size));
    std::vector<std::string> result(result_size);

    for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        result[i] = get_permutation(symbols, permutation_size, i);
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto list = list_permutations("01", 3u);
    for (auto& i : list) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

output:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Comment: You should avoid using `std::pow` to compute integer powers.  `std::pow` converts to a floating point type which could lead to an off by on error due to floating point imprecision.

Comment: @NathanOliver is `std::powl` a correct way to do it? or does one have to implement the own integer pow.

Comment: `powl` also using floating point math.  It is recomended to either make your own or find on you can use.  There is an implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851636/why-is-my-integer-math-with-stdpow-giving-the-wrong-answer

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, I added the implementation.